# Ipad app not retaining its dimension - reverts to iphone size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, dimensions

I need some help,
I created an iPhone App and it works great, I have made similar app for the iPad using my .h and .m files from my iPhone app, I created new .xib files for so the format fits the iPad dimensions and when I run in the simulation it stats alright but if I stop it and start it again using the iPad button (bottom middle button, I think is the HOME)on the simulator itself all my dimensions change to an iPhone size screen.

Summary.

1. The .xib files where created for the iPad dimensions.
2. I am not using storyboard, I have individual .xib files
3. When I fist run the app it works perfectly fine.
4. If I stop it and start it again using the button inside the iPad simulation, the dimension change to an iPhone size.
5. I do not have an iPad, so I can not check it out in real life I can only go by what the simulator does.

Can some please let me know how fix it, am I doing something wrong with my code?
Do I have to change some settings?

Your help is very much appreciated, I am going bald trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS simulator includes all applications created by you. And if you have created iPhone app with name MyApp and another iPad app with the same name then simulator will show two app. And running iPad app on iPhone, for example, simulator can lead to unexpected behavior. Check what app you run when you push Home button.

Try also to reset you simulator.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.